# Ionic Deformed screen when swiping the finger

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

When I slide my finger on the screen of an IONIC application the screen has just deformed, how can I solve this ?

Below is image of my screen:

[image]

The area wrapped in red  is the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve, after a long time I found an ionic class that had the following style:

```
    .pane, .view {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden; 
   }
```

And made the following changes:

```
    .pane, .view {
        position: initial;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        overflow: inherit;
   }
```

Comment: Well I guess I was not so happy in my solution, it funicated for IOS devices but for android I did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following CSS -- preventing the body element from overflowing the browser window.

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work for me, the following message is displayed: Invalid property value

Comment: Apparently this is not a horizontal scroll, but a deformation, something like a transform in the view, the problem is that I can not find what may be causing this